# Wireshark: Why it doesn't capture Client Hello request?

Tags: java, ssl, https, wireshark, tls1.2

On my local computer, I have a running Java application that sends a request to an external server via **https** protocol.

The main goal that I am going to achieve is:

- verify that communication between my local java application and remote server built based on TLS protocol version 1.2.

For this purpose, I am using Wireshark which allows me to monitor and analyze all network traffic on my laptop.

So, in Wireshark I added a new filter for request capture: "ssl" - to capture only https request than I run my application and checked what data was exactly captured by Wireshark:

The list of requests that were captured you can see on the screenshot below:
[image]

and I am a little bit confused because I do not see in the list "**Client Hello**" request, first request that was captured by Wireshark was "**Server Hello**".

I tried to repeat the experiment on my laptop a few times but the result was always the same - no "**Client Hello**" request captured by Wireshark.

Could you please provide any ideas why I do not see "**Client Hello**" request? 
Or maybe for some reason which I do not know missing "**Client Hello**" request is expected behaviour?

Comment: Client Hello is mandatory. With wireshark 2.4.5, I can see Client Hellos when capturing with filter = ssl. Not likely to happen, but ff you have several interfaces and only a part of the traffic is going through the one you are capturing, you would face similar issues.

Comment: (1) 'ssl' is not a valid capture filter. Do you mean a display filter, or some different filter and if so what? (2) Your display is missing not only ClientHello but apparently all other outbound messages that should be there. Are you sure you aren't filtering on address or port or somesuch that selects only inbound? If you capture and display with _no_ filter on either are messages in both directions displayed?